# iOS 6 Orientation with Navigation Controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, ios6, uideviceorientation

I have an app that works fine on ios 5,im trying to upgrade my app to work on ios 6, i had read tons of questions and tutorials about using ios 6 orientation,

my problem is when i call my rootViewController its work fine with me, but when i push any viewController the orientation look so bad  because i use the orientation to change the view sizes (my app support any orientation)

here is my code:

```
AppDelegate:


UINavigationController *nav =[ [UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:theView]  ;
self.window.rootViewController = nav;


- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window  // iOS 6
{

return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;


}




myFirstViewController:

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{

return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
 }

 -(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{

    [self viewWillAppear:NO];
 }

 -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
 return YES;
  }

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

[super viewWillAppear:NO];
if ( [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 6.0){
    if (pointRange.location != NSNotFound) {



UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

if( (interfaceOrientation >= 3)  ) {
     width=1024;
    self.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);

}


if   ( (interfaceOrientation == 1) || (interfaceOrientation == 2 )) {

    width=768;
    self.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);


}}
....etc
```

and i did the same in my second view, Hope to find why!!

Comment: probably, your next view controllers does not support orientations properly. because I've never had any same or similar issue at all. BTW, where have you read that you need to put that code in the `–viewWillAppear:` method? it is definitely not the usual way to handle the different orientations, and _that_ code could cause problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could always make an extension to the UINavigationController like this

```
@implementation UINavigationController (RotationFix)

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: it is not necessary to override the `–supportedInterfaceOrientations` method in every view controller.

Comment: @holex He isn't, each view controller provides a default implementation of `supportedInterfaceOrientations` that *can* be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

even i suffered for 2 days.. gone through many tutorials, blogs, forums, even apple docs.

So far i came to know, In iOS 6 each template of the app should be handled in a different ways.

So far the discussions were only for view based app, and these changes were not working on navigation based app or tabBar based app.

Finally i got the solution, it like this

Implement a subclass of these two types `UITabBarController` or `UINavigationController`.

Got to know from this [blog](http://code.shabz.co/post/32051014482/ios-6-supportedorientations-with-uinavigationcontroller). Thanks to Shabbir for the solution.